# decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value

Tags: python, django

I had pulled this project from its GitHub repo: [CGS Portal](https://github.com/silvareal/GGS-portal)

I also installed all the required packages to run the project, but the project could not able to run successfully.

```
Error Stack :
<br>python manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\chandan\Documents\GGS-portal-master\school\settings.py", line 25, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 70, in get
    raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: SECRET_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you have Django installed and confirm that you are actually referencing a settings file.

Do a `pip freeze` in your venv to confirm Django installed

Make sure you don't have to explicitly call a settings file when launching

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=yourproj.settings.production
```